# APEX 5.0.1 - interactive report using aliases give blank edit forms

Tags: oracle-apex

So I've been working on an application in Oracle Application Express 5, in which I have multiple interactive reports with an update form. I have noticed that when I use aliases in the SQL query of the report, the edit on the report stops working. When I want to edit a row, I just get the blank form for adding a new entry, even though I can see in the URL that the primary key has been sent.

Is this a known issue, and is there any way to make this work?

My column names are partly Croatian abbreviations, so leaving the original column names would be too messy.
Here's an example of my code which works:

select "SIFRA_A_P",
"SIFRA_P",
"NAZIV_P",
"CIJENA"
from "#OWNER#"."PJESMA"

Writing it like this

select "SIFRA_A_P" as "ALBUM",
"SIFRA_P" as "ID",
"NAZIV_P" as "TITLE",
"CIJENA" as "PRICE"
from "#OWNER#"."PJESMA"

makes it stop working properly.

Comment: can you make an example page in apex.oracle.com?

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=72325:2:5642479130297::::: here are two reports on the same page, sharing the same form page. the first report works fine, but had the database column names. the second one uses aliases but the edit doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go on your page where you have the problematic report, go at *Report Attributes* and in the *Link Column* section now you have something like this

```
Name                       Value
Item 1:P3_SIFRA_A_P        Value 1: #SIFRA_A_P#
Item 2:P3_SIFRA_P          Value 2: #SIFRA_P#
```

Change the `#SIFRA_A_P#` to `#ALBUM#` and `#SIFRA_P#` to `#ID#` in the value column.

Answer (score 0):

include `rowid` in your select statement.

```
     select rowid,"SIFRA_A_P" as "ALBUM", "SIFRA_P" as "ID", "NAZIV_P" as "TITLE", "CIJENA" as "PRICE" from "#OWNER#"."PJESMA"
```

Comment: SIFRA_A_P and SIFRA_P are the primary key, that's why there's no rowid. Some tables have rowid bit it still doesn't work